# How do i make this custom menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im trying to make this menu but i don't know how or what the name of this plugin could anyone tell me what name of this plugin or theme or menu name in wordpress plugin.

[image]

Does anyone know how to make this from scratch or is this plugin or something i would like to know how it was made since i don't know how to make this kinda of menu or is this icon box or feature box i need your advice on what name of this plugin or is custom made java-script or is it custom made?.

Comment: We can develop this type of menu after html development.

Comment: how can it be done when using as wordpress since i don't know how to make using in wordpress.It has some javascript when hovering the icon i think is made using jquery or javascript.

Comment: can u please provide code which you have try? so we can help you.

Comment: i got no code on this since i don't know how to implement but i found it on this website i wanted to know how it was made https://www.sourcefit.com/ <---- found  it on this website just wanted to know how it was made.

Answer (score 0):

**First off, this is my first post here, please do point if any mistakes.**

Secondly, you mentioned "plugin" so I take it you are not a dev. 
Moving on to a solution.

> I need your advice on what name of this plugin or is custom made
>   javascript or is it custom made?

The mentioned site and the ss, that's custom made.

You can go for 2 options, one is paid and one is free, but might not be as "cool" as their page.

**Paid Option is:**

https://codecanyon.net/item/hexagon-grid-gallery-addon-for-visual-composer/17962413?s_rank=1

**The free option is:**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/beehive/

I know well that this isn't 100% what you are looking for, but this does give you an idea what you are looking for.

I hope this lead will take you somewhere.

Good Day